# One tfvars for multiple modules in Teraform

Tags: terraform

I have multiple modules and i want have one tfvars for it.
Please advise.
variables.tfvars

```
    market = {
      tenant = {
        name         = "some name"
        description  = "some description"
        country_code = "some country code"
        code         = "some code"
      }
      webhook = {
        name        = "some name"
        description = "some description"
        url         = "some url"
        tenant_code = "some tenant code"
      }
    }
    `
```

There is my main.tf where described modules an how i call variables

```
module "tenant" {
  source       = "./modules/Tenant"
  for_each     = var.market
  name         = each.value.tenant.name
  description  = try(each.value.tenant.description, null)
  country_code = each.value.tenant.country_code
  code         = each.value.tenant.code
}
```

an error that i get

```
│   on main.tf line 34, in module "tenant":
│   34:   code         = each.value.tenant.code
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 6 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "tenant".
```

Comment: What does that mean? What multiple modules?

Comment: If all modules expect a `market` variable which is a map of other objects. Then why dont you just pass the `var.market` to the module

Comment: Marko, in my main.tf file I have several modules and i want to use one tfvars file for them.

Comment: Chris, it is not problem to use separate tfvars for each module, but i have several modules and i want to use only one tfvras file.

Comment: Please add an example to the question.

Comment: That doesnt make any sense, modules are designed to be an isolated bit of code. They can have their own tf_vars (but generally not recommended). Instead modules should be passed the vars they need

Comment: Chris, i undestand by my goal to have one file with tfvars

Comment: @Marko-e, i add my module, how i call variable and an error

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are using? Because looking at the error, the variable values you have shown look completely different.

Comment: @marko-e, yep here is a question - what's wrong with variables, or how I call variables

Comment: Well, this is wrong with the variables: `This object does not have an attribute named "tenant".`.

Comment: Yes it obvious but i dont understand how i need to configure them...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by the fact that the code you wrote searches for `tenant` inside the maps that only contain `name, description, country_code and code` as keys.

How for_each works over the entire map you are creating.

```
market = {
      tenant = {
        name         = "some name"
        description  = "some description"
        country_code = "some country code"
        code         = "some code"
      }
      webhook = {
        name        = "some name"
        description = "some description"
        url         = "some url"
        tenant_code = "some tenant code"
      }
    }
```

in the specific case for_each values will iterate over your map

Iteration one -> for_each will go over the following block

```
tenant = {
        name         = "some name"
        description  = "some description"
        country_code = "some country code"
        code         = "some code"
      }
```

and you will get the following values for the for_each arguments

each.key will be equal to 'tenant`

each.value will contain the following block

```
{
    name         = "some name"
    description  = "some description"
    country_code = "some country code"
    code         = "some code"
}
```

so you could access these individual attributes with each.value.<attribute_name>

```
each.value.name --> will have the value of "some name"
each.value.description --> will have the value of "some description"
```

In iteration 2, you will have each.key = webhook and each.value will contain the webhook block.

---

Assuming that the `tenant` module you are referencing is correctly defined (meaning it is expecting the variables you are feeding to it) you can call it like this

```
module "tenant" {
  source       = "./modules/Tenant"
  for_each     = var.market
  name         = each.value.name
  description  = try(each.value.description, null)
  country_code = each.value.country_code
  code         = each.value.code
}
```

Giving the details you provided, this should call the module twice, once for `tenant` and once for `webhook`